# Why are certain repeated keys ignored by interpretKeyEvents in NSResponder?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsresponder

I have an NSView that calls `interpretKeyEvents` for `keyDown` events. For some keys like the letter 'a', pressing and holding the key results in repeated calls to `insertText`. For other keys like 'x', `insertText` is called once and that is it. I would like press and hold to always call `insertText`. I'm guessing press and hold for these keys is interpreted as something else, but I cannot find it. I have implemented `doCommandBySelector` as described by the documentation, but that is never called either.

Below is a minimal example program that demonstrates the behaviour.

```
// clang++ -framework AppKit -o proof-of-concept proof-of-concept.mm

#include <stdio.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppView : NSView<NSTextInputClient>
@end

@implementation AppView

- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event {
    printf("keydown\n");
    [self interpretKeyEvents:[NSArray arrayWithObject:event]];
}

- (void)insertText:(id)string replacementRange:(NSRange)replacementRange {
    printf("insertText\n");
}

- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder { return YES; }
- (void)setMarkedText:(id)string selectedRange:(NSRange)selectedRange replacementRange:(NSRange)replacementRange {}
- (void)unmarkText {}
- (NSRange)selectedRange { return NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0); }
- (NSRange)markedRange { return NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0); }
- (BOOL)hasMarkedText { return NO; }
- (nullable NSAttributedString *)attributedSubstringForProposedRange:(NSRange)range actualRange:(nullable NSRangePointer)actualRange { return nil; }
- (NSArray<NSAttributedStringKey> *)validAttributesForMarkedText { return [NSArray array]; }
- (NSRect)firstRectForCharacterRange:(NSRange)range actualRange:(nullable NSRangePointer)actualRange { return NSMakeRect(0, 0, 0, 0); }
- (NSUInteger)characterIndexForPoint:(NSPoint)point { return 0; }

@end

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp, char **apple) {
    [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    [NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular];

    NSRect windowDimensions = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
    NSWindow *window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:windowDimensions
                                         styleMask:NSWindowStyleMaskTitled | NSWindowStyleMaskResizable
                                         backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                         defer:NO];

    AppView *windowView = [[AppView alloc] initWithFrame:windowDimensions];
    [window setContentView:windowView];
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];

    [NSApp run];
    return 0;
}
```

Is there an explanation for why `interpretKeyEvents` handles some key repeats by calling `insertText` and ignores others?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is the question, "Why are certain repeated keys ignored?" or "how to debug `interpretKeyEvents`?"? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit the question.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue but `insertText` is called for all repeated keys. Post a [mre] please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with the character accent popover menu. [This](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/1010) issue helped me figure it out. No popover was ever displayed for me, hence my confusion. I assume that is because I did not provide any system cursor information therefore the application doesn't know where to display it, however I haven't confirmed this.

Adding `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool: NO forKey: @"ApplePressAndHoldEnabled"];` disabled the accent popover for my application and solved the problem.

Comment: Why do you call `interpretKeyEvents` if you don't implement `NSTextInputClient`?

Comment: Input from the emoji and symbol character viewer only comes through on `insertText`, so I needed to implement that path anyway. `interpretKeyEvents` appeared to be the convention for passing character data from `keyDown` to `insertText`, as opposed to getting it out of the `NSEvent` and calling `insertText` myself.